# EclipseLink: @Enumerated is not taken into account on inherited fields from a parent Entity

Tags: java, eclipselink

Using *WildFly Full 17.0.1.Final (WildFly Core 9.0.2.Final) / EclipseLink 2.7.7 with MySQL server*, I have few fields (of enum type, of Instant as well) in a parent entity (`@MappedSuperclass`) that I want to inherit in few sub-entities.
The problem I have is that the annotation `@Enumerated(STRING)`, put in the parent entity fields, is not taken into account and EclipseLink is trying to persist the enums as integers instead of as strings.
The same issue with Instant type fields - the annotation `@Convert(converter = InstantConverter.class)` is not taken into account

When I move the fields to live in the child entities (not using inheritance), it works as expected.

Here is the code:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
public abstract class BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    private String id;
    
    @Column(name = "STATUS", nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private StatusEnum status;

    @Column(name = "TIMESTAMP", nullable = false)
    @Convert(converter = InstantConverter.class)
    private Instant timestamp;
    
    // ... getters, setters
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "child1")
public class ChildEntity extends BaseEntity {
  // other fields with getters and setters
}
```

The exceptions:

```
[EL Warning]: UnitOfWork(353321401)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.7.v20200504-69f2c2b80d): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '\xAC\xED\x00\x05sr\x00\x0Djava.time.Ser\x95]\x84\xBA\x1B"H\xB2\x0C\x00\x00xpw\x0D\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00aI\xD3\x86\x1B\xDD\xBCTx' for column 'TIMESTAMP' at row 1
```

```
[EL Warning]: UnitOfWork(597716366)--Exception [EclipseLink-3002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.7.v20200504-69f2c2b80d): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ConversionException
Exception Description: The object [FAILURE], of class [class java.lang.String], from mapping [org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DirectToFieldMapping[status-->d.s.STATUS]] with descriptor [RelationalDescriptor(d.e.ChildEntity --> [DatabaseTable(...)])], could not be converted to [class java.lang.Integer].
Internal Exception: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "FAILURE"
```

Any idea how to resolve this problem?

*Edit: There is no @Entity annotation on BaseEntity class as it is @MappedSuperclass. There is no table in DB behind it as well and this is the desired model. I just mention it, don't know if it is related to the issue.*

Comment: EclipseLink logging at finest will show you what it picks up, but a quick guess is that you don't have the BaseEntity packaged or setup to be processed as part of the persistence unit. Try explicitly listing it as a class within the persistence.xml, and check what EclipseLink is logging when it is deploying the persistence unit.

Comment: Actually my BaseEntity is listed in persistence.xml and I have the following log entries:
```
[EL Finer]: ServerSession(1867089876)--Class [xxx.BaseEntity] registered to be processed by weaver.

[EL Finest]: Begin weaver class transformer processing class [xxx.BaseEntity].
[EL Finest]: Weaved change tracking (ChangeTracker) [xxx.BaseEntity].
[EL Finest]: Weaved fetch groups (FetchGroupTracker) [xxx.BaseEntity].
[EL Finest]: End weaver class transformer processing class [xxx.BaseEntity].
```

Comment: Is it in the same jar as your child class? The message you shown is from wearing, which happens separately from the deployment process. There should be log entries from the persistence unit deployment, with EclipseLink logging all the entities, classes and mappings it finds. You might also want to check for another version of your entity class somewhere that might not have your annotations

Comment: I just noticed the AccessType.PROPERTY annotation. Try putting your annotations on the getter methods, or changing that to AccessType.FIELD